# Javascript Arreglo

Tags: javascript

tengo este script, funciona, este programa caputura la informacion de los meses del año, y los muestra, esta dentro de un ciclo for, el programa que tengo es el siguiente:

Quiero que imprima el mensaje del mes asi:

El primer mes es: 
El segundo mes es:
El tercer mes es:

..... mes es:

Es decir que estas palabras (primer, segundo, tercer) sea una variable o bien un acumulador, como le podria hacer para esto?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Mostrarmeses(meses) {
  var meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]; 
      
   document.write('<br>'); 

   for (var i = 0; i<12; i++) 
    {
 
       document.write('<br>'); 
      document.write("El mes es "+meses[i]);
        document.write('<br>'); 
    }
    
 }



</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Meses del año</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 body {
background-color:#FF0000; 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font color="#030303" face="georgia" size="5"> 
<center>
<TABLE BORDER=3 width="1000" height="50">
<TR><TD>
<font face="georgia" size="30">
<MARQUEE SCROLLAMOUNT=10 BEHAVIOR="alternate"><b>Meses del año</b></MARQUEE>
</font>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<button type='button' onclick='Mostrarmeses()'>Presiona para ver los meses</button><br/>

</center>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución: igual que tienes los meses, con un *arreglo*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Mostrarmeses(meses) {
    var meses = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
    var order = [ 'primer', 'segundo', 'tercero', 'cuarto', 'quinto', 'sexto', 'septimo', 'octavo', 'noveno', 'decimo', 'decimoprimero', 'decimosegundo' ];

     document.write('<br>'); 

     for (var i = 0; i<12; i++) 
    {

             document.write('<br>'); 
      document.write("El " + order[i] +" mes es "+meses[i]);
         document.write('<br>'); 
    }

 }

</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona!!!

Comment: Y como podria hacer, para que cuando de clic en el boton presiona para ver los meses, el resultado lo muestre en la misma ventana y no como ahorita, que cuando le das clic aparece en una nueva ventana sin formato?

Comment: Esto no va así, amigo @GrafftersSkates. Tienes que hacer una pregunta nueva :-)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está, el código te aparecerá en el mismo documento y además uso `DOMContentLoaded`, para asegurarnos que el documento haya cargado en su totalidad.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
document.getElementById("ver").addEventListener("click",m);
});
function m(){
  var meseslistos = document.getElementById("meseslistos");
  var meses = [
    "Enero",
    "Febrero",
    "Marzo",
    "Abril",
    "Mayo",
    "Junio",
    "Julio",
    "Agosto",
    "Septiembre",
    "Octubre",
    "Noviembre",
    "Diciembre"
  ],max = meses.length,i = 0,im = document.getElementById("meseslistos");
  var t = [ 'primer', 'segundo', 'tercero', 'cuarto', 'quinto', 'sexto', 'septimo', 'octavo', 'noveno', 'decimo', 'decimoprimero', 'decimosegundo' ];

  for(;i<max;i++){
   im.innerHTML += `<hr><b>El ${t[i]} mes, es: ${meses[i]}</b>`;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Meses del año</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
 body {
background-color:#FF0000; 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font color="#030303" face="georgia" size="5"> 
<center>
<TABLE BORDER=3 width="1000" height="50">
<TR><TD>
<font face="georgia" size="30">
<MARQUEE SCROLLAMOUNT=10 BEHAVIOR="alternate"><b>Meses del año</b></MARQUEE>
</font>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<button type='button' id="ver">Presiona para ver los meses</button><br/>
  <i id="meseslistos"></i>
</center>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```